# How to get user id from @username in Telegram using php

Tags: php-telegram-bot

Hi i'm working on a Telegram bot and i need to get the id of any one just form his username.
I searched for this question a lot but I did not find a solution and therefore I asked this question here, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) you can't. You can use the [`users.getUsers`](https://core.telegram.org/method/users.getUsers) method from the [Telegram APIs](https://core.telegram.org/api) (the ones for clients, not for Bots) but it's a bit complicated. Otherwise you can store in a database all `user_id` and `username` from users when they start the bot so you'll be able to get the `user_id` from the `username` and viceversa.